# CSS - Divs not centering with 'Auto: 0 Margin'

Tags: html, css, margin, centering

I am trying to create a menu bar in CSS, the main buttons (blue divs) should be centering inside the nav bar (orange divs) leaving equal spave beteen each button as well.

For some reason using `margin: 0` auto does not work.

here is my code:

```
.nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.nav__btn-cont {
    width: 20%;
}

.nav__btn {
    height: 50px;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

---

```
<div class="nav">
        <div class="w3-row">
            <div class="w3-col nav__btn-cont">
                <div class="w3-col nav__btn">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col nav__btn-cont">
                <div class="w3-col nav__btn">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col nav__btn-cont">
                <div class="w3-col nav__btn">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col nav__btn-cont">
                <div class="w3-col nav__btn">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col nav__btn-cont">
                <div class="w3-col nav__btn">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zpoqjc5s/

I was wodnering if anyone could pooint me in the right direction here, Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

*note that I am using bootstrap and w3.css*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `w3-col` class in the W3.css includes `float:left`.

```
.w3-col, .w3-half, .w3-third, .w3-twothird, .w3-threequarter, .w3-quarter {
    float: left;
}
```

...remove that for your buttons

```
    .nav__btn {
        height: 50px;
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: lightblue;
        float:none; /* added this */
    }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zpoqjc5s/1/)

Comment: many thanks, also: how can it include float: left when I have not specified it?

Comment: It's part of W3.css